# Add like count to a social network

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am almost done with my project, I completed every step and now I am stuck at the very least, I am not able to show the like count per post in my project.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("date").reverse()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
    number = request.GET.get('page')
    currentPosts = paginator.get_page(number)
    likeList = []
    try:
        for like in likes:
            if like.userLiking.id == request.user.id:
                likeList.append(like.postLiked.id)
    except:
        likeList = [] 
    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "currentPosts": currentPosts
    })
```

index.js

```
function like(id, likeList) {
    if (likeList.indexOf(id) >= 0) {
        fetch(`/remove/${id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result),
            window.location.reload()
        })
    } else {
        fetch(`/add/${id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result),
            window.location.reload()
        })
    }
}
```

index.html

```
  <div>
    <ul style="list-style: none">
      {% for post in currentPosts %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'profile' post.user.id %}"> From: {{ post.user }}</a></li>
        <li><h5 id="description{{ post.id }}">{{ post.description }}</h5></li>
        <li>{{ post.date }}</li>
        {% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.user %}
          <button id="editButton{{ post.id }}" onclick="edit({{ post.id }})">Edit</button><br>
          <div id="text{{ post.id }}"></div>
          <div id="save{{ post.id }}"></div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          {% if post.id not in likeList %}
            <button class="likebtn" id="{{ post.id }}" onclick="like({{ post.id }}, {{ likeList }})">Like</button><br>  
          {% else %}
            <button class="unlikebtn" id="{{ post.id }}" onclick="like({{ post.id }}, {{ likeList }})">Unlike</button><br>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        <p id="likeCount{{ post.id }}">Likes: </p>
        ----------------------------------
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

models.py

```
class Like(models.Model):
    userLiking = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userLiking")
    postLiked = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="postLiked")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.userLiking} liked {self.postLiked}"
```

I tried: post = Post.objects.get(id=id) - but index does not take id as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate a count to each item in your queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count

posts = Post.objects.annotate(likes=Count("postLiked")).order_by("date").reverse()
```

Then you can simply access it in the template via `{{ object.likes }}`. *Rename the object name as required.*

Read more in the Django documentation about [Generating aggregates for each item in a QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to render it, but I am not sure how, please could you show me?

Comment: In your template, it will be `{{ post.likes }}`.

Comment: It worked! Gosh I can't believe it, finally! After several days of struggling! Marco really thank you so much from the bottom of my heart, you are great!!!